# BlackBerry 10.2 Map is supporting overlay maps?

Tags: blackberry-10

We experienced so many problems to port a geomapping application to BlackBerry 10. 6-7 months a go, BlackBerry 10 Map service was not supporting overlay maps.

Are there any improvements on BlackBerry 10.2 on it?

Comment: If you have an existing application on other platforms that you wish to bring to BB10, you are in a very good position to encourage BlackBerry to provide these improvements. As per my answer below, I believe it would be fairly easy for BlackBerry to implement APIs to provide the functionality. They may just need enough encouragement to bring it out in 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

The design of the mapping system in BB10 seems very well suited to a developer providing a source for overlay tiles -- either from a network server source or locally generated from data -- but I have not seen any indication that such API additions are on the road map.

There are some small improvements in 10.2. We have [GeoPolyline](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__platform__geo__geopolyline.html) and [GeoPolygon](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__platform__geo__geopolygon.html) classes. Unfortunately while using these classes with the 10.2 Beta API does not produce compilation or run time errors, I can't get them to produce visible marks on the map either.

The ability to overlay data on a map or, by suppressing the default background tiles, creating all new maps that provide the same UI experience to the user as other mapping solutions on the platform seems like too powerful a tool to pass up. I hope they get around to it soon.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any improvement yet...

Comment: Disagree, there is improvement with Markers and stability. But still far from wonder.